# htaccess redirect params from iOS doesn't work

Tags: android, ios, apache, .htaccess, redirect

With this redirections rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} app
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.eu/$1 [NC,L,R=301,E=HTTP_X_HEADER_WITH:%{HTTP:HTTP_X_HEADER_WITH}]
```

works fine with calls with a parameter "param1" from any browser and from android devices.
But with iOS the "param1" It not arrives

If I use Android or a computer to request an URL. In the landing page after the redirection:

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST["param1"])) {
  // Never here, "param1" is set.
}
```

With iOS:

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST["param1"])) {
  // The param1 it not set.
}
```

Is there any special configuration to the .htaccess for an iOS device to pass the params correctly?

Comment: this is in server side right? what it means with android or ios is difference?

Comment: This looks like an iOS problem. Look into the access.log file, to see what is requested, when you do this with iOS.